# Laravel Ajax Login Tries To Redirect

Tags: ajax, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am trying to remove default Laravel behavior of redirected authenticated user once authenticated.

I commented in `LoginController.php`

```
//protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

And also changed the `AuthenticatesUsers` vendor file to return JSON instead of a redirect on login success:

```
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

        /*return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
                ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());*/

                 return response()->json(['SUCCESS' => 'AUTHENTICATED'], 200);
    }
```

But still when I successfully login I see in my Chrome network tab that I get an error, because it is trying to redirect me to `/home` which is an undefined route, leading to the error and halting my Laravel SPA.

Why is Laravel continuing to direct me to `/home` even after I comment it out and change the Vendor files?

Comment: Check whether user is authenticated or not and show the code of routes(web or api) file @SummerDeveloper

Comment: @PassionInfinite User is authenticated, but the routes file does not include a definition for `home`, I commented it out: `//Route::get('home', 'HomeController@homepage')->name('home');`

Comment: Did you run composer commands dump-autoload and config:clear after changing the files? @SummerDeveloper

Comment: @PassionInfinite The former yes, the latter no let me try.

Comment: @PassionInfinite Tried both and still same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a middleware problem.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            //return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

In, `app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php`